# I want build+launch new app builds without plugging in my phone. Is there a way to download and launch APK files from within an Android app?

Tags: java, android, mobile

I'd like to be able to compile an Android app on my desktop, upload it to my phone and launch the app without having to plug in my phone via USB. I want this for 1) convenience when developing and 2) SD card access isn't available when plugged in.

One idea I had was to write an app that would download the app from the computer wirelessly (e.g. or via a website the app was uploaded to) and then launch the app. The APK doesn't need to be installed in this process, but if it did, I wouldn't want there to be any user interaction. Is this possible? I suspect it won't be because of security implications.

Are there any alternative ways to do this? I essentially want some way to do over the air updates for an application. Perhaps I can upload a single class file for the app that can be launched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The APK doesn't need to be installed
>   in this process, but if it did, I
>   wouldn't want there to be any user
>   interaction. Is this possible?

Automating the install? Yes. No user interaction? No. The user will get the normal installation and permissions screens. And it will be flat-out impossible (at the moment) on AT&T-specific phones (e.g., BACKFLIP, Aria), which prohibit this sort of thing.

> Are there any alternative ways to do
>   this?

If there is, it's a security hole, as you suggest.

Also, your very issue seems flawed. SD card access is certainly available with the device plugged into USB -- just don't mount the storage.